# If Exists Update Else Insert with VB.net (sql parameterised query)

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm hoping to use the following update\insert method to speed up my application insert\updates:

```
UPDATE [Application_Type_Table] 
SET ApplicationType='Test Value'
WHERE ID='1'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
INSERT INTO [Application_Type_Table] VALUES ('Test Value')
```

How would I do this with sql parameters? the rowcount function will be picked up as a parameter due to the @@.

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = _
"UPDATE [Application_Type_Table]" _ 
SET (SET ApplicationType=@TestValue" _ 
"WHERE ID=@RecordID IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO [Application_Type_Table] VALUES (@TestValue)"
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that this is the problem? I've seen `sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"` used multiple times, and the @-signs did not pose a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern is known as an [UPSERT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert). The modern way of doing this is to use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) in SQL Server 2008 e.g.

```
MERGE INTO Application_Type_Table AS target 
USING (
       VALUES (@RecordID, @TestValue)
      )  AS source (ID, ApplicationType)
   ON target.ID = source.ID
WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN UPDATE 
           SET ApplicationType = source.ApplicationType
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
   THEN INSERT (ID, ApplicationType) 
           VALUES (ID, ApplicationType);
```

Comment: @madlan: In theory MERGE can be better optimized because it only needs to perform one pass. As ever with performance, it depends on many factors. See: Optimizing MERGE Statement Performance (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  [Application_Type_Table] WHERE "_
"ID='1') BEGIN INSERT INTO " _
"[Application_Type_Table] VALUES ('Test Value') END ELSE BEGIN UPDATE [Application_Type_Table]"_
"SET ApplicationType='Test Value'"_
"WHERE ID='1' END"
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest moving the query to a stored procedure. Queries (especially multi-statement ones) don't really belong hard-coded into one's application IMO. Doing so would also have the bonus of alleviating your problem ;)

Comment: I'd argue the opposite. SPs are fine for basic CRUD stuff; but not more complex multi-statement subroutines. Ten years ago it was common to envision an application as "a database with some business code around it". But today our definition of a software application is different. The business layers lies outside the database. As far as performance, the DBMS reuses the execution plan for any SQL statement, not only stored procedures, so performance is equivalent once compiled.