# if exists update else insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to know if the next piece of code is correct:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
   "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT count(*) from Raspunsuri where id_intrebare=2)" +
   "Insert INTO Raspunsuri VALUES(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,2,@ip,@idsesiune)" +
   "else" +
   "UPDATE Raspunsuri SET raspuns=@raspuns,cod_numeric_personal=@cnp,data_raspuns=@data,id_intrebare=2,ip_user=@ip,id_sesiune=@idsesiune WHERE id_intrebare=2", con);
```

All the parameters are correct that I want to insert but it seems this piece of code doesn't do the insert or update.Do you have any suggestions?it's a sql query combined with c#..

Comment: have u tried sqlcommand.executereader

Comment: already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599709/insert-vs-update

Comment: this should throw exception. Query needs spaces ...`@idsesiune)elseUPDATE`...

Comment: Also: I would recommend to **always explicitly specify** the list of columns in an `INSERT` statement to make your code more resilient to changes in the table structure: `INSERT INTO dbo.Raspunsuri(Col1, Col2, ....., Col6) VALUES(.......) `

Comment: possible duplicate of [If Exists Update Else Insert with VB.net (sql parameterised query)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708689/if-exists-update-else-insert-with-vb-net-sql-parameterised-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspect the string that's created by that command: some words need spaces between them.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from Raspunsuri where id_intrebare=2)" +
                " Insert INTO Raspunsuri VALUES(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,2,@ip,@idsesiune)" +
                " else" +
                " UPDATE Raspunsuri SET raspuns=@raspuns,cod_numeric_personal=@cnp,data_raspuns=@data,id_intrebare=2,ip_user=@ip,id_sesiune=@idsesiune WHERE id_intrebare=2", con);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

No because you select `count` that has always a value.

**select a column or `*` instead.**

#### Sample

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
   "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT id_intrebare from Raspunsuri where id_intrebare=2) " +
   "Insert INTO Raspunsuri VALUES(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,2,@ip,@idsesiune) " +
   "else " +
   "UPDATE Raspunsuri SET raspuns=@raspuns,cod_numeric_personal=@cnp,data_raspuns=@data,id_intrebare=2,ip_user=@ip,id_sesiune=@idsesiune WHERE id_intrebare=2", con);
```

Comment: You, too, would need **spaces** at the end of each line - otherwise the statement **will fail** (SQL Server cannot interpret `)elseUPDATE Raspunsuri...`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command?

Comment: @Rares: you can [learn how on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) - the **entire** SQL Server documentation is online, and available for everyone

Answer (score 1):

You can try executing the query in `SQL Server Management Studio` window first. This will give you an easy way to debug the things

Answer (score 0):

I think the blank spaces are missing between the "else" statement
Also ensure that you have provided all the columns in the values part