# Update if exist, else insert threw my DAL

Tags: c#, t-sql

I'm trying to build a update statement if a record exists, else insert a new record. I have a DAL that makes the insert ok, but now I need to add the update for the existing case.
I have this working code for insert:

```
    public static void saveArticle(DateTime mtime, int mid, string mname, double homeodds, double awayodds, double drawodds)
    {
       var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE");
       var dateTimeInfo = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(culture);
       var dateTime = DateTime.Today;

       int weekNumber = culture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dateTime, dateTimeInfo.CalendarWeekRule, dateTimeInfo.FirstDayOfWeek);
       string mroundY = dateTime.Year.ToString();
       string mroundW = weekNumber.ToString();
       string mround = mroundY + mroundW;

       //Console.WriteLine(mround);

       SqlCommand saveArticle = new SqlCommand("Insert Into gameTB(mround, mtime, mid, mname, homeodds, awayodds, drawodds) VALUES (@mround,@mtime,@mid,@mname,@homeodds,@awayodds,@drawodds)");
       saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mround", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mround;
       saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mtime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = mtime;
       saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mid;
       saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = mname;
       saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@homeodds", SqlDbType.Float).Value = homeodds;
       saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@awayodds", SqlDbType.Float).Value = awayodds;
       saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@drawodds", SqlDbType.Float).Value = drawodds;

       DAL.ExecuteNonQuery(saveArticle);
    }
```

I have tried to add an IF statement after reading this [forumpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698568/if-exists-update-else-insert) but it doesn't work with the logic I'm using.

How can I accomplish an update with the else insert command I already have?

Comment: What platform is your database server? How coupled is this code to it? Have you looked into using a MERGE command? Or a stored procedure to handle the logic for inserting/updating?

Comment: Instead of showing the code that works but doesn't do what you intend, show the code that expresses what you intend but doesn't work, and describe the error you are getting.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns number of rows affected. So you can execute `update` command first, check the result and execute `insert` if it is 0. If you are using SQL Server, you can do the same thing in single command using `@@rowcount`

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [If Exists Update Else Insert with VB.net (sql parameterised query)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3708689/299327)

Comment: I would recommend changing this `saveArticle.Parameters.Add` to implement using `saveArticle.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Param, paramValue);` let the server handle the Dataype

Comment: @KyleHale - I've looked in to MERGE but cant put the parts together.

Comment: @mbeckish - See the code below I have tried with

Comment: @IliaG - I have tried to call @@rowcount but as you can see in my latest example something is terrible wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSERT vs. UPDATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599709/insert-vs-update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [INSERT vs. UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599709/insert-vs-update) I managed to get it to work. I followed a similar article that leave basic thinks that was not obvious for me. I tried this before but I made some big mistakes so that I thought that I was way out of track. Here is my working code;

```
    SqlCommand saveArticle = new SqlCommand("if Exists(Select 1 from gameTB where mround = @mround AND mid = @mid)\r\n" +
    "UPDATE gameTB SET homeodds = @homeodds, awayodds = @awayodds, drawodds = @drawodds Where mround = @mround AND mid=@mid\r\n" +
    "else\r\n" +
    "Insert Into gameTB(mround, mtime, mid, mname, homeodds, awayodds, drawodds) VALUES (@mround,@mtime,@mid,@mname,@homeodds,@awayodds,@drawodds)");

    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mround", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mround;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mtime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = mtime;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mid;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = mname;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@homeodds", SqlDbType.Float).Value = homeodds;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@awayodds", SqlDbType.Float).Value = awayodds;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@drawodds", SqlDbType.Float).Value = drawodds;

    DAL.ExecuteNonQuery(saveArticle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have the `mid` in your code. If this is the `id` of the record in the database and you are not using any other `id` (autogenerated one), then the easiest would be to execute a select query if there exists the record with the same id. If the select query returns something, you should update, and if not do the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server you can rewrite your command as follows

```
var saveArticle = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE gameTB SET homeodds = @homeodds, awayodds = @awayodds, drawodds = @drawodds Where mround = @mround AND mid=@mid
if (@@rowcount = 0)
    Insert Into gameTB(mround, mtime, mid, mname, homeodds, awayodds, drawodds) VALUES (@mround,@mtime,@mid,@mname,@homeodds,@awayodds,@drawodds)");
```

The `@@rowcount` contains number of records affected by the last statement. So if `update` was successful it will contain `1` and `insert` will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a MS SQL 2012. I have looked into the MERGE command but don't understand how to use it.

I have tried to do like this but I receive many errors when trying to build and I'm guessing I'm way out of track, right?

```
    SqlCommand updateArticle = new SqlCommand("UPDATE gameTB SET homeodds = @homeodds, awayodds = @awayodds, drawodds = @drawodds Where mround = @mround AND mid=@mid");
    DAL.ExecuteNonQuery(updateArticle);
    if (@@rowcount = 0) Then
    SqlCommand saveArticle = new SqlCommand("Insert Into gameTB(mround, mtime, mid, mname, homeodds, awayodds, drawodds) VALUES (@mround,@mtime,@mid,@mname,@homeodds,@awayodds,@drawodds)");
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mround", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mround;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mtime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = mtime;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mid;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = mname;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@homeodds", SqlDbType.Float).Value = homeodds;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@awayodds", SqlDbType.Float).Value = awayodds;
    saveArticle.Parameters.Add("@drawodds", SqlDbType.Float).Value = drawodds;
    DAL.ExecuteNonQuery(saveArticle);
    EndIf;
```

Comment: `@@rowcount` is a SQL server variable, not a C# one. You need a single command object with query defined as you can see in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MERGE just set your command like so

```
SqlCommand saveArticle = new SqlCommand(@"
    MERGE INTO gametb AS target 
    using ( VALUES (@mround, 
          @mtime, 
          @mid, 
          @mname, 
          @homeodds, 
          @awayodds, 
          @drawodds ) ) AS source (mround, mtime, mid, mname, homeodds, awayodds, 
          drawodds) 
    ON ( source.mround = target.mround 
         AND source.mid = target.mid ) 
    WHEN matched THEN 
      UPDATE SET mtime = source.mtime, 
                 mname = source.mname, 
                 homeodds = source.homeodds, 
                 awayodds = source.awayodds, 
                 drawodds = source.drawodds 
    WHEN NOT matched THEN 
      INSERT (mround, 
              mtime, 
              mid, 
              mname, 
              homeodds, 
              awayodds, 
              drawodds ) 
      VALUES (source.mround, 
              source.mtime, 
              source.mid, 
              source.mname, 
              source.homeodds, 
              source.awayodds, 
              source.drawodds );");
```

Comment: I get an error saying this; Must declare the scalar variable mround?

Comment: I messed up the update part [see the revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15235381/revisions), but I would have expected `The multi-part identifier "source.mtime" could not be bound.` not the scalar exception. Then again I'm using SQL 2008, but I wouldn't expect that to change in 2012.